# Exclude results from a mysql query using regexp

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I got a table with the following values

```
titles:
Accountant
Auditor
Bookkeper
Forensic Accountant
Tax Accountant
```

I'd like to select all the titles that don't contain "Accountant" in it, i'm currently trying with

```
SELECT * FROM careers WHERE title NOT REGEXP '^Accountant'
```

But it still selects "Forensic Accountant" and "Tax Accountant"

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't really know about regexes in MySQL, but if it's anything like PHP, `^Accountant` means all matches **starting with** Accountant. What happens if you remove the `^` ?

Comment: Is regular expression even needed for this?

Answer (score 2):

use `not like` instead of regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM careers WHERE title NOT LIKE '%Accountant%'
```

See the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c098e0/2)

Comment: This helps, but what if the title input is "Tax Accountant" instead?

Comment: @Agrus it will alse excluded, because `%` means any character

Answer (score 0):

The regex is wrong, you are using the caret(^) , which means the words you are excluding should start with Accountant, instead remove the caret and you should be good

```
SELECT * FROM careers WHERE title NOT REGEXP 'Accountant'
```

To exclude something user defined, based on what jobtitle is selected, do something like the following

```
SELECT * FROM careers WHERE title NOT REGEXP (SELECT regexMatch FROM careers WHERE title = "Tax Accountant")
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, It should exclude "Tax Accountant" also

Comment: For instance:
    SELECT * FROM careers WHERE title NOT REGEXP 'Tax Accountant'

It still fetches "Accountant" and "Forensic Accountant"

Comment: Yes because Account and Forensic Accountant does not match "Tax Accountant".   If you have "Tax Accountant" and you want to exclude all results with just Accountant I would have to know what context it is in. Why do you try "Tax Accountant"?

Comment: Because an user might select through an UI "Tax Accountant" instead of "Accountant", hence, "Accountant" and "Forensic Accountant" should be excluded from the result

Comment: Okay, then I would add to the database an extra column, where you put the regex, you want that specific carrer to exclude. Then you can use the code I added to this answer. It requires adding a column to careers called `regexMatch`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE instead of REGEXP like this:

```
SELECT * FROM careers WHERE title NOT LIKE '%Accountant%';
```

Comment: My bad :( I ment to edit my entry, instead I clicked on delete

Comment: I am not copy your answer. I run this query and post answer.  @Jens